# Is using the reference to a control in a background worker thread safe?

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety, backgroundworker

Let's say that I have a dictionary of controls and strings. If I run a background worker, is it thread safe to use the control reference to access the string corresponding to the control?

```
Dictionary<Control, string> _ctlDict;
//Called in the main thread
public void Persist()
{
  foreach (var control in Controls)
  {
    _ctlDict.Add(control, control.Name);
  }
}

//Called in the background worker
public string GetControlName(Control ctl)
{
  return _ctlDict[ctl];
}
```

This should be OK because I am not using any of the controls' properties - I am just using the control's reference, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't access properties or methods of the control, yes, it's perfectly safe. It's just an object reference, the fact that it points to a control doesn't matter...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you have to be sure, is Persist and GetControlName must not be called at same time.

Comment: Well, I call persist before I even start the background worker.